# how to return a vuejs view in laravel routing file

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a **Laravel + VueJS application** and I am having trouble with the following issue:

- What method would I use to return the Vue Page. Return View doesnt work which is what I expected but I am unaware what I put there.

Here's my code:

routes/web.php-

```
Route::get('/pizzas', function () {
    return view('Pizzas');
});
```

the Vue file directory is
resources/js/Pages/Pizzas.vue

Comment: Vue is using one-page concept. Not work like that. Use API json request-response and init page what load vuejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add your component to app.js(Im assuming you already have this in your resources folder) with:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('pizza-component', require('./Pages/Pizzas.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

And in your laravel blade, use the component like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <pizza-component></pizza-component>
</div>
```

This works for me when trying to use a Vue compnent in a blade template file